# Problems overwriting file in application folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a file called `PolicyLookup.sql` that sits in my application's root folder. My app loads this file into a text box, so that users can edit it and overwrite the original file by pressing a save button. This all worked perfectly during test, however after deployment users are unable to save the file due to write issues within `C:\Program Files`.

Is there a way around this - or is there a better way to implement this type of thing? One solution that springs to mind for me is placing the contents of the `PolicyLookup.sql` file within a User Setting - however it intrinsically feels wrong to me to put the entire contents of a file within a settings variable.

Comment: What is the actual write issue?  It it user permissions or something else?  The specific error would be helpful.

Comment: Specific Error is: "5: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\myapps\\myapp\PolicyLookup.sql' is denied."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinary users do not have write permissions on `%ProgramFiles%`. If you need to save a configuration file then put it in a subfolder of `%APPDATA%` (which for me is `C:\Users\Gord\AppData\Roaming`) or some other place where a regular user is allowed to write.

Comment: Okay - that would make sense! I am not clear how I tell Visual studio to place one of my assets in %APPDATA%, but I can see how that would resolve the issue. When I look on the properties of the asset within Visual Studio I can see the File Name, and I can see a non-editable full path - but I can't see anywhere that allows me to specify a location.